# String searching for u_char*

Tags: c, string, substring

How do i look for a substr in string pointed by u_char* as all C functions take a char* as argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `u_char` is a typedef for `unsigned char`, then the normal trick is to use the standard functions and apply casts.

That is very ungainly, though, so you might instead use macros that apply the casts automatically.

```
#define STRSTR(haystack, needle) \
                 ((u_char *)strstr((char *)haystack, (char *)needle))
```

Or you might write `inline` functions if your compiler supports C99.

```
static inline u_char *ustrstr(u_char *haystack, u_char *needle)
{
    return (u_char *)strstr((char *)haystack, (char *)needle);
}
```

Or you might simply write cover functions:

```
u_char *ustrstr(u_char *haystack, u_char *needle)
{
    return (u_char *)strstr((char *)haystack, (char *)needle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since u_char is defined as a typedef of unsigned char in BSD type sockets implementations (sys/types.h in *nix and winsock.h in Windows) and if that's your context, you'll be safe to apply a cast to `(char*)` just before passing them to the standard C functions. If that's not your context, then you have to find the declaration of u_char and confirm that it is of type unsigned char or equivalent and only then it's safe to apply the cast.